# How to Optimise Php mysql query for quicker execution

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

Have a php script for copying data from one database to another database. It is working fine but it is taking lot of time. Approximately 1000 rows are inserted every minute meaning 100,000 rows takes upto 2 hours to be copied ! Can this time be reduced by optimising the below code ? Tried to remove subquery and put left join but it did not work.

Edit - The script is selecting (choosing) data from one database db1 according to words or their combinations. It is matching using explode/implode. Then, it is creating new table of that name in other database db2. And then inserting the selected data into the new database db2. Now, it is selecting data from 2 tables from old database. It is using subquery for that. Will using left join speed up the execution ?

**My Code**

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 30000); 
ini_set('default_charset',"utf-8");

include('config_collect.php');
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$keywordId = $_GET['id'];
require_once("config_duplicate.php");
?>

<?php 

try
{
$kewyQ = $db->query("SELECT * FROM collections where id = 
$keyId"); 
$kVal = $kewyQ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$table = trim($kVal['words']);

//Create table
$Q = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$table` (
`id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
`t_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`t_text` TEXT,
`user_name` varchar(100),
`place` varchar(100),
`time` datetime,
`description` TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) 
CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci";
$db2->query($Q);

// Count all records based on words
if (preg_match('/\s/',$table)) {
$keySpace = explode(" ", $table);
if(count($keySpace) > 1){
    $squery = "SELECT * FROM t WHERE t_text LIKE 
 '%".implode("%' AND t_text LIKE '%", $keySpace)."%' ";
 }else{
    $keyval = $keySpace[0];
    $squery = "SELECT * FROM t WHERE t_text LIKE '%$keyval%' ";
 }
 }else{
$squery = "SELECT * FROM t WHERE t_text LIKE '%$tablename%'";
}
```

Then...

```
$allOBJ = $db->query($squery);

while($row = $allOBJ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $tId = $row['t_id'];
    $t_text = addslashes($row['t_text']);

    //Get user name and location
    $description = "";
    $place = "";

    $name = addslashes($row['user_name']);
    $time = $row['time'];
    $userj = $db->query("SELECT description,place FROM users WHERE 
    user_name='".$row['user_name']."'");
    if($row2 = $userj->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $description = addslashes($row2['description']);
        $place = addslashes($row2['place']);

    } 

    $chKQ = $db2->query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `$tablename` WHERE t_id = 
   '$tId' "); 
    $countg = $chKQ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    if($countg[0]==0){
    $db2->query("insert into `$table`(t_id, t_text, user_name, place, 
    time, description) VALUES ('$tId','$t_text', '$name', 
    '$place','$time', '$description' )");
    }
}
} catch (PDOException $e) {
die("ERROR: " . $e->getMessage());
}

?>
<div>Duplication success</div>
```

(SQL examples, from comment:)

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  collections
    where  id =30 ;
SELECT  *
    FROM  t
    WHERE  t_text LIKE '%red%'
      AND  t_text LIKE '%car%' ;
SELECT  description,place
    FROM  users
    WHERE  user_name='Rick';
INSERT
     into  $table(t_id, t_text, user_name, place, time, description)
    VALUES  ('30','Nice red
              and  big car', 'Rick', 'California','2017/06/03', 'developer' 
            )
```

Comment: Perhaps you could show us examples of each SQL statement?

Comment: @RickJames SELECT * FROM collections where id =30 ; SELECT * FROM t WHERE t_text LIKE '%red%' AND t_text LIKE '%car%' ; SELECT description,place FROM users WHERE 
    user_name=`Rick`; insert into `$table`(t_id, t_text, user_name, place, 
    time, description) VALUES ('30','Nice red and big car', 'Rick', 
    'California','2017/06/03', 'developer' )

Answer (score 1):

In the last 2 projects I had in my company I had to work with similar cases.
We had to copy something like 10M rows of data across network and the first solution that came to mind was using php. That approach clearly failed.

Instead I replaced it with this piece of code which works amazingly fast since it's pure mysql

```
$this->logger->info('Dumping the data');
    $biDbUser = $this->getContainer()->getParameter('bi_database_user');
    $biDbPass = $this->getContainer()->getParameter('bi_database_password');
    $biDbHost = $this->getContainer()->getParameter('bi_database_host');
    $biDbName = $this->getContainer()->getParameter('bi_database_name');
    $dumpFilePath = rtrim(sys_get_temp_dir(), '/').'/'.uniqid('init_dump_bi').'.sql';

    exec(sprintf(
        'mysqldump -u %s -p%s -h %s --single-transaction --compress %s %s > %s',
        $biDbUser,
        $biDbPass,
        $biDbHost,
        $biDbName,
        $contextConfig->getBiTableLast(),
        $dumpFilePath
    ));
    $this->logger->info('Dump completed. Now loading it to our db.');

    $dpDbUser = $this->getContainer()->getParameter('dp_database_user');
    $dpDbPass = $this->getContainer()->getParameter('dp_database_password');
    $dpDbHost = $this->getContainer()->getParameter('dp_database_host');
    $dpDbName = $this->getContainer()->getParameter('dp_database_name');
    exec(sprintf(
        'cat %s | mysql -u %s -p%s -h %s %s',
        $dumpFilePath,
        $dpDbUser,
        $dpDbPass,
        $dpDbHost,
        $dpDbName
    ));


    unlink($dumpFilePath);

    $columns = array_diff($contextConfig->getColumns(), ['timestamp']);
    $query = sprintf(
        'INSERT INTO %s (%s) SELECT %s FROM %s',
        $contextConfig->getInvoicingTable(),
        implode(',', $columns),
        implode(',', $columns),
        $contextConfig->getBiTableLast()
    );

    $this->logger->info('Data moved to our db. Now inserting from bi to our table.');
    exec(sprintf('mysql -u %s -p%s -h %s %s -e "%s"', $dpDbUser, $dpDbPass, $dpDbHost, $dpDbName, $query));
    $this->logger->info('Insert done.');


    $query = 'DROP TABLE '.$contextConfig->getBiTableLast();
    exec(sprintf('mysql -u %s -p%s -h %s %s -e "%s"', $dpDbUser, $dpDbPass, $dpDbHost, $dpDbName, $query));

    $this->logger->info('Finished synchronisation BI->DP.', [
        'context' => $contextConfig->getContextCode()
    ]);
```

Obviously there are lots of variables that I'm not going to Explain about but here are the main parts of this script.

```
exec(sprintf(
        'mysqldump -u %s -p%s -h %s --single-transaction --compress %s %s > %s',
        $biDbUser,
        $biDbPass,
        $biDbHost,
        $biDbName,
        $contextConfig->getBiTableLast(),
        $dumpFilePath
    ));
```

I get the connection configs from symfony(In your case you should have it from your connection) and call mysqldump. I use --single-transaction since the user has read-only access. Also using --compress avoids putting too much pressure on the data center network.

```
exec(sprintf(
        'cat %s | mysql -u %s -p%s -h %s %s',
        $dumpFilePath,
        $dpDbUser,
        $dpDbPass,
        $dpDbHost,
        $dpDbName
    ));
```

Once the dump is done using this command you will put the dumped data into the destination database.
And finally

```
$query = sprintf(
        'INSERT INTO %s (%s) SELECT %s FROM %s',
        $contextConfig->getInvoicingTable(),
        implode(',', $columns),
        implode(',', $columns),
        $contextConfig->getBiTableLast()
    );

    $this->logger->info('Data moved to our db. Now inserting from bi to our table.');
    exec(sprintf('mysql -u %s -p%s -h %s %s -e "%s"', $dpDbUser, $dpDbPass, $dpDbHost, $dpDbName, $query));
```

I use mysql insert select query to pass the data from the new dumped table to our table.
I tried to use the pdo connection to do the last call but I guess there is a delay until the table is available globally for all sessions of mysql. So PDO kept saying can't find the table.

Hope it help.

Comment: I am not well versed with this type of code. Can you please provide any link for documentation of the same ? Can you tell how to left join instead of subquery in my code ?

Comment: Sorry man but there is no documentation on such a thing :)
Also there is no subquery here and this is just to give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

**Plan A:**

The fastest way to copy all the rows from one table to another is to do it in a single query:

```
INSERT INTO new (a,b,c)
    SELECT a,b,c FROM old;
```

No row counting, no loops, no back and forth between MySQL and PHP, etc.

I'm unclear on what exactly are doing, but see if you can work backward from that goal.

**Plan B:**

Since you seem to be walking through a bunch of tables, maybe this would be better:

Outside of PHP, do

```
mysqldump ... old_db  |  mysql ... new_db
```

Note: This can also provide the identical `CREATE TABLE` for the new_db.

**Plan C:**

This is sort of a combination of the above two.  It creates a CSV file for the transfer.

```
SELECT a,b,c FROM old_tbl INTO OUTFILE ...;
LOAD DATA INFILE ...;
```

**More** (after seeing sample SQL)

Are there multiple 'identical' tables represented by `$table`?  If so that is a big red flag in schema design; please explain your intent.

Well, I don't grok the use of `words` and `collections`, but this combines the insert with two selects:

```
INSERT INTO  $table
      ( t_id, t_text, user_name, time,
        description, place ) 
SELECT  t.t_id, t.t_text, t.user_name, t.time,
        u.description, u.place
    FROM  t
    JOIN  users u  ON u.user_name = t.user_name
    WHERE  t_text LIKE '%blue%'
      AND  t_text LIKE '%car%' ;
```

Comment: The code is not so simple. The script is selecting (choosing) data from one database db1 according to words or their combinations. It is matching using explode/implode. Then, it is creating new table of that name in other database db2. And then inserting the selected data into the new database db2. Now, it is selecting data from 2 tables from old database. It is using subquery for that. Will using left join speed up the execution ?